# How to get access token from refresh token google in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, google-api

How to get access token from refresh token Google in asp.net ?

> You shouldn't design your application based on specific lifetimes of
>   access tokens. Just assume they are (very) short lived.
>
> However, after a successful completion of the OAuth2 installed
>   application flow, you will get back a refresh token. This refresh
>   token never expires, and you can use it to exchange it for an access
>   token as needed. Save the refresh tokens, and use them to get access
>   tokens on-demand (which should then immediately be used to get access
>   to user data).

Comment: `Save the refresh tokens, and use them to get access tokens on-demand (which should then immediately be used to get access to user data`. If you are curious, you can explore writing your lib for it. Otherwise, avoid re-inventing the wheel and use [available libraries](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2)

Answer (score 0):

```
 private bool GetNewAccessToken(GoogleTokenModel GoogleTokenModelObj)
{
    try
    {
        string Url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
        string grant_type = "refresh_token";
        string redirect_uri_encode = UrlEncodeForGoogle(ReturnUrl);
        string data = "client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&refresh_token={2}&grant_type={3}";

        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
        string result = null;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string param = string.Format(data, ClientID, ClientSecret, GoogleTokenModelObj.Refresh_Token, grant_type);
        var bs = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(param);
        using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            reqStream.Write(bs, 0, bs.Length);
        }

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }

        var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var TokenData = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<GoogleTokenModel>(result);

        GoogleTokenModelObj.Access_Token = TokenData.Access_Token;
        if (TokenData.Refresh_Token != null)
            GoogleTokenModelObj.Refresh_Token = TokenData.Refresh_Token;
        //GoogleTokenModelObj.LastAccessDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        //Update the refresh and access token in DB for next login usage
        //GoogleCalendarManager.UpdateRefreshTokenInGoogleAppointmentOAuth(GoogleTokenModelObj);
        XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "App_Data\\XMLfile.xml");
        XmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//User[@UserID='1']").Attributes["AccessToken"].Value = TokenData.Access_Token;
        XmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//User[@UserID='1']").Attributes["RefreshToken"].Value = TokenData.Refresh_Token;
        XmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "App_Data\\XMLfile.xml");

        return true;

    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```